# What software is available for showing keystrokes on the screen?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, presentations, keystrokes

I will be demoing software which is very shortcut driven and it would be helpful to the audience if they could see what keys I am pressing. I need something that will show keystrokes on the screen. A bonus would be if the software could tell when I am pressing key combos (CTRL + C, CTRL + V, SHIFT + CTRL + TAB... etc)

Anyone have any recommendations for me?

Comment: No one ever says what operating system they're using. Why is that?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Yeah, a lot of new questions suffer from this. Look at [my closed question](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2020/having-to-ask-for-the-users-os)... :-(

Comment: Sorry about that! It is a windows machine.

Answer (score 3):

http://dan.hersam.com/2009/05/01/how-to-display-keystrokes-for-screencasts-on-windows/ mentioned these options:

- <strike>[OSDHotKey]</strike>[1](http://www.romeosa.com/osdHotkey/help.html) (autohotkey exe)
- [ShowOFF](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#ShowOff) (autohotkey exe)
- [KeyBoardOnScreen](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/KeyboardOnScreen.ahk) (autohotkey script)